# How to change screen transition to "right to left" when a button is pressed using python code, kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to make a button to go to the previous screen using python code, the problem is that it is using the default transition animation (which goes from left to right) and it looks weird. I didn't have a problem doing that with the kv file, but in this specific screen I must use python code to change that property. I want to make it go from right to left, since the default animation looks weird.

The way I do it in the kv file:

`root.manager.transition.direction = "right"`

I've tried:

`back_button.on_release = lambda: setattr(self.manager, "transition", "right")`, but this doesn't work so :)

The complete screen code:

```
class Contraindicaciones(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Scrollview
        self.scrollview_contraindicaciones = MDScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size = (Window.width, Window.height))

        # GridLayout
        layout_contraindicaciones = MDGridLayout(orientation = "lr-tb", spacing = "60dp", padding = "20dp", size_hint_x = 1, size_hint_y = None, cols = 2)
        layout_contraindicaciones.bind(minimum_height = layout_contraindicaciones.setter("height"))

        # Go Back Button:
        invisible_label1 = MDLabel(text = "")
        invisible_label1.size_hint_y = None
        invisible_label1.size_hint_x = 0.5
        invisible_label1.height = dp(50)

        back_button_layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        back_button = MDFillRoundFlatButton(text = "Anterior", font_name = "fonts/Lato-Bolditalic.ttf")
        back_button.haling = "left"
        back_button.size_hint_y = None
        back_button.size_hint_x = 0.5

        back_button.on_release = lambda: setattr(self.manager, "transition", "right")
        back_button.on_release = lambda: setattr(self.manager, 'current', 'c_t')


        back_button_layout.add_widget(back_button)
        layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(back_button_layout)
        layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(invisible_label1)

        #title
        title_label = MDLabel(text = "Contraindicaciones", halign="left")
        title_label.font_size = "15dp"
        title_label.size_hint_y = None
        title_label.size_hint_x = 1
        title_label.font_name = "fonts/Lato-Bolditalic.ttf"
        title_label.height = dp(50)

        # Invisible Label
        invisible_label2 = MDLabel(text = "")
        invisible_label2.size_hint_y = None
        invisible_label2.size_hint_x = 0.25
        invisible_label2.height = dp(50)

        # Title and Invisible Label to not mess the rest up
        layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(title_label)
        layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(invisible_label2)

        contraindicaciones = ["Hemorragia intracraneal (HIC) previa", "Lesión vascular cerebral estructural conocida",
        "Neoplasia intracraneal maligna conocida ya sea primaria o metastásica", "Accidente cerebrovascular isquémico en un plazo de 3 meses",
        "Sospecha de disección aórtica", "Hemorragia activa o diátesis hemorrágica", "Traumatismo craneoencefálico cerrado importante o traumatismo facial en los últimos 3 meses",
        "Cirugía intracraneal o intramedular en un plazo de 3 meses", "Hipertensión no controlada grave", "En caso de estreptoquinasa, el tratamiento previo debe ser dentro de los 6 meses previos"]

        for contraindicacion in contraindicaciones:
            size_checkbox = dp(32)
            size_labels = dp(12)
            checkbox = MDCheckbox(size_hint = (0.5, None), size = (size_checkbox, size_checkbox))
            label = MDLabel(text = contraindicacion, size_hint = (0.5, None), size = (size_labels, size_labels))
            label.font_name = "fonts/Lato-Italic.ttf"
            layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(label)
            layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(checkbox)

        # Button and invisible label
        invisible_label3 = MDLabel(text = "")
        invisible_label3.size_hint_y = None
        invisible_label3.size_hint_x = 0.5
        invisible_label3.height = dp(50)

        next_button = MDFillRoundFlatButton(text = "Continuar", font_name = "fonts/Lato-Bolditalic.ttf")
        next_button.haling = "right"
        next_button.size_hint_y = None
        next_button.size_hint_x = 0.5
        next_button.on_release = lambda: setattr(self.manager, 'current', 't_y')

        layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(invisible_label3)
        layout_contraindicaciones.add_widget(next_button)

        #Se agrega Grid a Scroll
        self.scrollview_contraindicaciones.add_widget(layout_contraindicaciones)
        self.add_widget(self.scrollview_contraindicaciones)
```

Here's the code of the screenmanager and the app:

```
class WindowManager(MDScreenManager):
    pass
```

```
class PatricApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.previous_screen = ""
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (255,255,255,255)
        self.root_widget = Builder.load_file("patric.kv")
        return self.root_widget
    def show_time_picker(self):
        time_dialog = MDTimePicker()
        time_dialog.open()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PatricApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a callback twice to `next_button.on_release`, so you are overwriting the callback intended to change the transition with the callback that changes the Screen.

You can use a "normal" function/method as a callback and perform both actions on it. On the other hand, you must modify `self.manager.transition.direction` not `self.manager.transition`.

```
class Contraindicaciones(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # ...
        back_button.bind(on_release = self.back)
        # ...

    def back(self, *_):
        self.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        self.manager.current = 'c_t'
```